# How to integrate User permissions in Ldap

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

My target it so assign to user permissions. For example:

User "John" belong to role ROLE_CUSTOMERS and have the permissions of: 'READ_MAILS", 'ADD_MAILS'.

User "David" belong to role ROLE_USERS and have the permissions of: 'DELETE_MAILS'

I managed to map users and roles to the ldap directory.
Users -> John,David
Groups -> ROLES_CUSTOMER,ROLE_USERS

But I am missing the permissions part.

I don't know how to declare the 'READ_MAILS", 'DELETE_MAILS','ADD_MAILS' attributes/permissions/task or however you call it.

1. How I assign each permission to a user at the ldap side?
2. How ill be able to retrieve those permissions in the spring security side before letting a specific user do some operation.

*I am not sure this requirement I am looking for called 'permission' please correct me if I wrong.

thanks,
ray.

Comment: What about for local users, for them you are able to assign roles/permissions?

Comment: What do you mean for them? Nothing is implemented yet. I am trying to figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is fine-grained permissions / entitlements. Those are not typically stored in LDAP but rather in another solution e.g. an authorization service.

With respect to Spring Security, this [article](http://www.javabeat.net/2011/04/separating-roles-and-permissions-in-spring-security/) may help. Also consider the Spring API documentation on [permissions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html).

I would recommend you consider a standards-based approach using XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. With XACML you use roles that come from LDAP and then you write rules e.g. `a manager can edit accounts that are in the same region as the user.`. Check out XACML either at the [OASIS website](http://oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml) or on Wikipedia for some more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So what do you think. That I won't be able to achieve permissions with LDAP with the regular Spring security approach? About XACML: you have any practical example using spring security xacml and ldap for permissions? Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on how complex your authorization model is. In principle, LDAP groups / roles and Spring Security should be enough. XACML is worth it if you have relationships such as the one I gave as an example. Can you give us an example of the authorization logic you'd like to implement? Here's a better article on Spring Security's Authorization Architecture: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/authz-arch.html